# How to add custom key words in json schema?

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I want generate value using json schema. But json schema not support file type.So i add custom key word **inheritType** . Now i validate this schema it throw Exception.
 So How to slove this problem. and How to add custom keyword in json schema

> This My Json Schema

```
{ 
    "type" : "object" ,
    "properties" : {
        "file" : {
           "type" : "string" ,
            "inheritType"  : "File"
        }
    }
}
```

> This is my java code throws Exception

```
{ 
   "level" : "error",
   "schema" : {
   "loadingURI" : "#",
   "pointer" : "/properties/file/inheritType" ,
   "ignored" : ["inheritType"]
}
```

Comment: The JSON Schema specification says unkown keywords should be ignored. What library are you using and which language?

Comment: I am using json-schema-validator-2.2.6.jar.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want to add the keyword to those allowed, based on this [github issue comment](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator/issues/148#issuecomment-74169492).

> This is an implementation choice. The primary goal of these messages
>   is to, in fact, detect spelling mistakes (consider pattenrProperties
>   for instance).
>
> As the report says, these warnings will be ignored; therefore you need
>   not worry about these.
>
> Note that you have the option to either:
>
> configure the log level so that those warnings do not appear in the
>   final log, or update the dictionary of keywords so that this keyword
>   is recognized.

I can't see how to do this in the javadocs though. Sorry.